# Tile/concatenate high resolution PDF files with imagemagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I've 9 high quality PDF files. I want to merge them into one large PDF of 3x3. I then want to turn this into a PNG file. I want to keep the resolution/sharpness during this process so that on the resulting PNG I can zoom right in and still see the fine detail. I thought I might do this with imagemagick but I'm struggling. Any ideas please?

I've tried this to merge them together to start with. It works, but the quality doesn't remain.

```
montage input_*.pdf -background none -tile 3x3 -geometry +0+0 output.pdf
```

Please note that file size and size of resulting image isn't an issue. I've no need to print it or anything like that. It's for viewing on a computer only.

Here is a sample of three of the PDF files:

1) https://www.dropbox.com/s/qc094jg1nkfk0jw/input_1.pdf?dl=0

2) https://www.dropbox.com/s/gb4u8r7bxg8lw2r/input_2.pdf?dl=0

3) https://www.dropbox.com/s/97dhi42wrvfxfd2/input_3.pdf?dl=0

Each PDF is 1071 x 1800 pts (using pdfinfo).

Thanks

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than stick with PDF and then merge and then convert to PNG, you may be better to extract the images as PNG in the first place and then concatenate the PNG files like this:

```
pdfimages -png input_1.pdf a
pdfimages -png input_2.pdf a
pdfimages -png input_3.pdf a

# Combine them side by side
montage a-*png -background none -tile 3x3 -geometry +0+0 output.png

# Or combine with "convert"
convert a-*.png +append result.png
```

The second document seems to have a mask...

```
pdfimages -list input_1.pdf
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image   12000 20167  icc     3   8  image  no         9  0   807   807 1260K 0.2%

pdfimages -list input_2.pdf
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image   12000 20167  icc     3   8  image  no         9  0   807   807 5781K 0.8%
   1     1 smask   12000 20167  gray    1   8  image  no         9  0   807   807  230K 0.1%

pdfimages -list input_3.pdf
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image   12001 20167  icc     3   8  image  no         9  0   807   807 2619K 0.4%
```

Comment: There seems to be some issue with extracting the images from your second and third input files for some reason - were they generated a different way?

Comment: I presume you are aware that the 3 images are each 12,000x20,000 pixels, so the result is a 0.75 Gigapixel image?

Comment: Hi Mark. I wasn't aware that my second and third images were different. A colleague wrote the R script for generating them. Let me look into that and get back to you. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: PS: I am going to try and make something like this with the resulting image: http://build-failed.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html

Comment: Hi Mark. I've created the files afresh. But I'm trying to run this and it doesn't look right:  pdfimages -png input_1.pdf a

Comment: That should give you a file called `a-0001.png`

Comment: Can your R-friend maybe generate a PNG directly, instead of a PDF?

Comment: Ah. It seems I don't have a recent version of pdfimages . Trying to figure out how to update it now.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 - pdfimages version 0.18.4

Comment: Ok, I am on OSX with `pdfimages` version 0.29.0

Comment: Ok. Thanks Mark. I will look into how to update my version of pdfimages . I will also look into getting the R code to output PNG from the start.

Comment: It may be in a package with `Poppler` as part of its name.