# Finding high density pages in a pdf file with cv2

Tags: python, opencv, pdf, image-processing, pymupdf

I have multiple pdf files from which I am trying to identify which are the high density pages. Here are examples of an high density pages from the code output. I want to make it such that the 3rd and 4th example pages aren't classified as high density.
[image: High Density Image Example]

[image: High Density Image Example]

[image: Page wrongly classified as high density example 1]

[image: Wrongly classified high density page example 2]

The approach I am using is the following:

- Getting an average page threshold value and comparing it with the pixel value
- If it less than the threshold I am converting it to black(0) else white (255)
- Then getting the ratio of black to white pixels and if the ratio value is >25 then I am considering it as a high density page

This approach is working great, but it has the following restrictions:

- If the text font is small, thus there being more text on the page; It identifies it as a high density page.
- If there are multiple images on the page, then it identifies it as a high density page.
- If there is a background to the page, then it identifies it as a high density page.

I want to get rid of these limitations, here are the functions I am using.

```
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import time
import tqdm

def get_pdf_paths(directory_path):
    pdf_paths = glob.glob(f"{directory_path}/*.pdf")
    return pdf_paths

def get_number_of_pages(pdf_path):
  try:
    pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    number_of_pages = pdf_document.page_count
    pdf_document.close()
    return number_of_pages
  except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
    return None

def convert_pdf_to_image(pdf_path, page_number=0):
  pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)
  pdf_page = pdf_document.load_page(page_number)
  pix = pdf_page.get_pixmap()

  img = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((pix.h, pix.w, pix.n))
  return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def calculate_density_threshold(image):
  average_density = np.mean(image)
  threshold = int(average_density)
  # print(threshold)
  return threshold

def binarize_image(image, threshold):
  _, binary_image = cv2.threshold(image, threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  return binary_image

def calculate_black_to_white_ratio(image):
  total_pixels = image.size
  black_pixels = np.sum(image == 0)
  white_pixels = total_pixels - black_pixels
  if white_pixels == 0: #happens when blank page
    white_pixels = 1
  ratio = black_pixels / white_pixels
  return ratio#, white_pixels
```

The code:

```
%%time
directory_path = "/path/to/directory"
list_of_pdf_paths = get_pdf_paths(directory_path)
print(f'Number of pdfs {len(list_of_pdf_paths)}\n')
p=[]
for pdf_path in list_of_pdf_paths:
  print('----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
  print(f'{os.path.basename(pdf_path)}\n')
  no_of_pages = get_number_of_pages(pdf_path)
  p.append(no_of_pages)
  print(f'No. of pages in {os.path.basename(pdf_path)} is {no_of_pages} \n')
  condition = True

  for page_number in range(0,no_of_pages):
    # Convert PDF page to grayscale image
    pdf_image = convert_pdf_to_image(pdf_path, page_number)
    
    # Calculate average density and threshold
    threshold = calculate_density_threshold(pdf_image)

    # Binarize the image using the calculated threshold
    binary_image = binarize_image(pdf_image, threshold)

    # Calculate black to white pixel ratio
    ratio = calculate_black_to_white_ratio(binary_image)*100  #binary_image
    # print(f"Black to white pixel ratio for page {page_number+1} is {ratio:.4f}")

    if ratio > 100: #blank page
      continue
    elif ratio > 25:
      condition = False
      print(f'Page number {page_number+1} is of high density')
      
  if condition == True:
    print('No high density pages found.\n')
```

I am also wondering it there is a better approach/solution to this problem.

Comment: Consider adding examples of pages that your code labels as *"high density"* but which are not.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ok I will do that; Is "high density" the proper term for this? I don't know if there is a term for it and maybe i am searching solutions for a wrong phrase.

Comment: We might need to wait for someone clever to come along and answer, but while we are waiting, there's a package called *"poppler"* which contains a tool called `pdfimages`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31407509/2836621 You could try running that on your PDF to see what images it can extract - you could then maybe locate them on the page and overdraw the entire image with white so its density doesn't count... of course, if if finds your circuit diagrams which you presumably do want, we may have to rethink.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried your suggestion but with a different approach; I used fitz to get image bounding boxes and then redacted the bounding box white before running it through the code. This works great but it only works if the PDF is electronic in nature. It won't work when there are scanned images as pages; (not willing to use image segmentation models here as it will become memory and time extensive).  Will have to think of a different approach for them for now.

Comment: @KJ As i said, I am not sure if the term "high density" is right to be used in this case. Let me explain the problem better, for example in picture 1 and 2 you will find it hard to read the text or to make proper sense out of it in an instant; I am referring to them as "high density". While in picture 3 and 4 you can make sense better and faster as compared to picture 1 and 2. 
Yes, if there is background in the page or if there are multiple images in them then my code is going to say that the page is high density. Which is technically right. But what i want is only pic 1 & 2 as high density.